# Local TFstate does not migrate to remote location (Azure Blob)

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-cdk

I am using Azure Blob to store my state. I follow these [steps] (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/blob/main/docs/working-with-cdk-for-terraform/remote-backend.md#migrating-local-state-storage-to-remote) the only difference is that I am using the AzurermBackend. The problem is when I do `terraform init` it does not migrate the existing state to the blob, it just create a new one in which there is no resources, so when i execute `cdktf diff` terraform says that it needs to create each resource that was already created in the local state. I checked the file the file is empty. I also tried with thr `stack.addOveride` that don't works too.  Next thing I did is I execute the `TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform init`  and got the following logs:

```
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] Adding temp file log sink: /tmp/terraform-log769761292
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.0.9
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.16.4
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"/usr/bin/terraform", "init"}
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /home/shurbeski/.terraformrc
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory terraform.d/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/shurbeski/.terraform.d/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/shurbeski/.local/share/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/ubuntu/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/local/share/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /var/lib/snapd/desktop/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:00:03.228+0100 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"init"}

Initializing the backend...
2021-12-20T16:00:03.229+0100 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "2abdb28d-45b7-02a5-d5b1-851b3c446ef3"
2021-12-20T16:00:03.229+0100 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2021-12-20T16:00:03.233+0100 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/bin"
2021-12-20T16:00:03.233+0100 [INFO]  Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
2021-12-20T16:00:03.233+0100 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "ea01857e-a1b7-080a-dda5-a5081c10f48b"
```

Actually it just creates a new state, so I tried `TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform init -migrate-state` and got the following logs:

```
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] Adding temp file log sink: /tmp/terraform-log411077971
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.0.9
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.16.4
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"/usr/bin/terraform", "init", "-migrate-state"}
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /home/shurbeski/.terraformrc
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory terraform.d/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/shurbeski/.terraform.d/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /home/shurbeski/.local/share/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/ubuntu/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.541+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/local/share/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.542+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /usr/share/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.542+0100 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory /var/lib/snapd/desktop/terraform/plugins
2021-12-20T16:08:07.542+0100 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"init", "-migrate-state"}

Initializing the backend...
2021-12-20T16:08:07.543+0100 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "4af0afde-830e-1836-4bb8-4013609be0ad"
2021-12-20T16:08:07.970+0100 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2021-12-20T16:08:07.974+0100 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/bin"
2021-12-20T16:08:07.974+0100 [INFO]  Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
2021-12-20T16:08:07.975+0100 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "472594f8-73dc-abe6-3691-5c7bddfb715e"
```

Even this didn't work.

The only thing that works if when I manually copy the tf state file and put it in the blob for the state, but i I do not like that.

Any  ideas how would I get terraform to ask me if I want to migrate my pre-existing tfstate?

This is my code in the cdktf stack:

```
// new AzurermBackend(mystack,  {
//   storageAccountName: "cdkremotebackendtest",
//   containerName: "test1",

//   subscriptionId: "",
//   key: "terraform.tfcdk-demo.tfstate",

//   accessKey: "",


// });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to specify a backend provider under main terraform config. If you don't specify it it will assume local so no migration. Something like this

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
--------------------
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "cloud"
    storage_account_name = "cdkremotebackendtest"
    container_name = "test1"
    key = "terraform.tfcdk-demo.tfstate"
  }
}
```

More info on backends: https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration